# Does the react-virtualized Masonry component support setting the scrollTop or scrollToIndex values?

Tags: scroll, masonry, react-virtualized

I've implemented a Masonry layout that adjusts dynamically to the window size and it all works very well. I calculate its height and width and reset the cell measurements when any outside dimensions change.

I just need to be able to programmatically slide into view a specific item while it is being edited as well as scroll back to top programatically. Is this possible? I've tried to set scrollTop or scrollToIndex but it has no effect (unlike List). I have the feeling that I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!

Unfortunately, the `Masonry` component does not currently support a `scrollTop` prop (other than a partial support required to work with `WindowScroller`). I would be willing to review a PR adding this functionality, but whether it landed would depend on the complexity. :)